# How to get the download speed from youtube extractor C#

Tags: c#, youtube

Im using Youtube Extractor to download an Audio from youtube .
I want to know how to calculate the speed .

[Youtube Extractor Link](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor)

Please help me with this

Thanks

Comment: Calculate what speed..?

Comment: Then it should quite simply be `fileSize/timeToDownload`. File size you can get from whatever the library gives you back (an array of bytes? file location?) And you can time how long the call to the library takes.